# why should equation be preferred to gather for single-line equations?

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath, typography

There are numerous questions/answers on which equation-type environment to use under which circumstances.  For a single-line equation, various people have expressed a preference of `equation` over `gather` (even in the `amsart` class or using `amsmath`) because they deem it simpler or because they feel that `equation` should be used for single-line equations because `gather` is *intended* for multi-line equations.  I get all that.

My question is: are there any typographical advantages of using `equation` over `gather` in the single-line case, i.e. are there examples in which `gather` produces undesired spacing or other problems when `equation` works well?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\noindent
This equation
\begin{equation}
x =y
\end{equation}
looks the same to me as this equation:
\begin{gather}
x=y
\end{gather}
Doesn't it?

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

ok, in light of David Carlisle's comment, let me ask a follow-up question.   What would be the easiest way of changing LaTeX's behavior to potentially use the `shortdisplayskip` feature in multi-line equations, also?  (I'm not asking whether or not you think this is desirable.)

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but you do not get the `\shortdisplayskip` feature using gather,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  thank you, thought it would be too, but failed to find one.

Comment: My search foo seems more accurate:-) (well that is align rather than gather but same comments apply)

Comment: You had the insight that `align` and `gather` were equivalent in this respect, whereas I didn't.

Comment: arguably that means that it is only a duplicate if you already know the answer, which is not too good. Do you want to re-open and add a gather-answer? (I'll ask in chat what other regulars think)

Comment: It doesn't matter to me now that I know the answer. Whatever you think is best.

Comment: Better ask a new following up question, giving there a link to this question.

Comment: I am not judging whether your update, formally, worth reopen or not. But `amsmath` is dirty and there were already thousands of questions about tiny spaces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- added the dup as an item in "often referenced questions, with slightly more scrutable description.