# Why use `equation` instead of `gather`

Tags: equations, gather

I know `equation` accepts only one line, and `gather` accepts several lines.
Then when there is only one line, is there any advantage of `equation` over `gather`?
If not, why does `equation` exists at all?
May I always use `gather`?
Or, is there some caveat?

Comment: Equation contains a space saving feature that the others does not. If the text line before the equation is short and the equation is also short, then equation uses the short distance above the equation, the other envs always use the long distance. If you know what to look for you'll notice it in the output

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267833/why-should-equation-be-preferred-to-gather-for-single-line-equations?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.9596

Comment: Oh, the post is about `align`. If the same is true for `gather`, then I get it.